# document.getElementById('textbox').focus() not working after submit form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, focus

I am trying to implement a simple form, and I am trying to set the focus on the first textbox in the form after submit, it's just not working. I could not use the code snippet on this site because I am using localStorage, and it didn't allow me to use it)

Here's my code on Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZemVpz

Here's how my HTML looks like for a quick reference:

```js
document.getElementById('formBookmark').addEventListener('submit', addBookmark);

function addBookmark(e) {
    var siteName = document.getElementById('txtSiteName').value;
    var siteUrl = document.getElementById('txtSiteUrl').value;
    if (!validate(siteName, siteUrl)) {
        alert("Please fill the blank fields");
        return;
    }

    var newBookmark = {
        siteName: siteName,
        siteUrl: siteUrl
    }

    var bookmarks = getlocalBookmarks() || [];

    bookmarks.push(newBookmark);
    localStorage.setItem('tf-bookmarks',JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    //trying to set focus here
    document.getElementById(formBookmark).reset();
    document.getElementById("txtSiteName").focus();
    
    fetchBookmarks();
    e.preventDefault();
   
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form id="formBookmark">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtSiteName">Site Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="txtSiteName" id="txtSiteName" class="form-control" placeholder="Google" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtSiteUrl">Site Url:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="txtSiteUrl" id="txtSiteUrl" class="form-control" placeholder="http://google.com"/>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnAddLink" type="submit">Add Bookmark</button>
            </form>
```

I can use body onload event to do this, but what if I have more than one form on the page. Why that line of code to set focus through JS isn't workin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, it's just a small typo - you forgot to add quotes around 'formBookmark' here:

```
//trying to set focus here
document.getElementById(formBookmark).reset();
document.getElementById("txtSiteName").focus();
```

Don't forget to use 'Developer Tools' console to quickly catch bugs like this.
Just for completeness on Chrome 'Developer Tools' can be found here:
[image]

and now console clearly shows how your code crashes on .reset() call just 1 line before you're trying to .focus():

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but when I run it locally, the page reloads, I don't see anything in the console. Isn't the e.preventDefault() supposed to prevent the page from loading?

Comment: Yes, it supposed to prevent and it does prevent page from loading upon form submission on my end. Tested both on codepen.io and locally - all works good (as expected): when I comment out "e.preventDefault();" then it does reload the page on submit. Try to add 'alert(123);' after your line "e.preventDefault()" - does it get executed (you should see alert popup if all good) or you forgot to add mentioned before quotes on your local setup?-)